# Automating multiple imagemagick commands

Tags: batch-file, pdf, imagemagick

I have hundreds of PDFs containing powerpoint handouts (with 6 (2x3) slides on each page) that I want to convert to single slide per page PDF (or PPT, ultimate goal is importing to OneNote properly).

So far I have succeeded in finding the correct commands to create single, nicely cropped JPEG files for each slide:

```
C:\"Program Files"\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16\convert.exe -density 300 C:\Users\matt\Desktop\cmd\5.pdf -gravity Center -crop 80%x+0+0 -quality 100 -sharpen 0x1.0 C:\Users\matt\Desktop\cmd\output.jpg
```

This split up the PDF pages and crops away page numbers for easier trimming later.

```
C:\"Program Files"\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16\convert.exe -crop 2x3@ C:\Users\matt\Desktop\cmd\output-0.jpg C:\Users\matt\Desktop\cmd\output-0%d.jpg
```

This divides slides up from one page.

```
C:\"Program Files"\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16\convert.exe -trim C:\Users\matt\Desktop\cmd\output-00.jpg C:\Users\matt\Desktop\cmd\output-00%d.jpg
```

This trims the borders of each slide.

How would I automate all this into a drag and drop script so I can quickly convert a PDF into a collection of JPEGs or from there a full PDF?

Answer (score 0):

After tons of reading I figured it out. I wrote a .bat (batch?) first setting the working directory as the location the .bat was located in. Then I did all the imagemagick operations with proper use of leading zeros to get the right order (if you use *.jpg it will go through 1.jpg, 11.jpg, THEN 2.jpg). The operations basically took any .pdf in the folder and turned it in JPGs, manipulated them as I needed, then when finally in proper order, made a single PDF.

Simple in theory, tricky in  practice.